# Has the meaning of the word “actual” and its derivates (actuality, actually, etc.) anything to do with temporality, in English?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

In my language, the words “actual”, “current” and “present” are somehow time-related, and their meaning is very close with some differences, obviously.

Searching in dictionary the meaning of the word “actual” gave no result for such a meaning.

Comment: *temporality?* A new word to me! I searched and wonder what exactly you mean by that in this context?

Comment: @Maulik, it is the meaning #2: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/temporality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question makes this usage note make sense. (Before reading your question, I suspected that there must be some languages that can cause such confusion.)

> **Get it right: actual**
>   Don't confuse actual with current or present. Actual is not used for referring to things that are happening now or that exist now. Use current or present to express these ideas:
>   ✗ The <del>**actual law**</del> requires every young man to do military service.
>   ✓ The **current law** requires every young man to do military service.
>   ✓ The **present law** requires every young man to do military service.
>   ✗ They have to work together to improve the <del>**actual situation**</del>.
>   ✓ They have to work together to improve the **current situation**.
>   ✓ They have to work together to improve the **present situation**.
>   Actual is used for referring to what is really true or exact:
>   The reports cites 554 AIDS cases, with 2600 persons infected with HIV. But officials concede that the actual number may be closer to 8000.
>   <sub>Source: [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american)</sub>

Comment: Those " wrong" examples are only wrong **if** you intend to convey the "present" meaning. The sentences as such are fine, but mean something else than the "current/present"-versions.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For all Latin languages speakers such confusion can be caused.

Comment: I kept wondering about it for a while. (I'm sure that my not knowing anything about Latin is the reason that kept myself wondering.) I'm glad that you pointed it out. Thank you for the question!

Answer (score 1):

**Actual** *can* refer to a situation at the present time, but it hardly ever has that connotation.

As a matter of fact, it usually does not carry an explicit temporal meaning, but it rather refers to a state of reality, as opposed to a possible, theoretical or erroneous state.

> We expected the air plane to be flying at 30,000 feet, but its actual altitude was only 10,000 feet.
>
> The company was expected to have had a bad year, but its actual figures showed a 30% increase in net profit.

In both cases, we are not strictly speaking of a *present* or *current* situation, but rather about a *factual* situation that (in these examples) contradicts expectations.

So, although *actual* can certainly refer to a present situation, I would use **present** or **current** if you want to emphasize the temporal implications.

For **actually** I cannot think of any time-related meaning, it *only* ever refers to what is real as opposed to what is not, or turns out not to be, real.

**Actuality** on the other hand *can* refer to current affairs, and most definitely has temporality in some cases. However, it can also refer to a general state of affairs that is more or less always true, so then it loses the temporal implications.

All in all, it seems that you found nice example of how meanings can shift inconsequently between an adjective, an adverb and a noun that without doubt, once had the same meaning.
Give people enough time and they will find new ways of using English until all rhyme and reason seems to disappear. :)

Comment: What about *you may think that these many sixes and fours are not possible by any batsman and it happens only in highlights of the match. But **actually** this is a live match, surprised?*

Comment: Oh yes, I got it (#3). It talks about the **present moment**: http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/ACTUALLY

Comment: OK, I see it is in the reference, but your example does not give me any idea about the fact the match is currently on-going. _Live_ might give that idea, but you could show me an integral recording of the match and tell me, actually, this is an integral recording. And it would certainly not be happening at the present moment.

Comment: Actually, I am less than convinced by the example sentence from wordwebonline.

Comment: Ah, you said it just that ;) *actually, this is an integral recording* - it certainly means actually, at present, what you are watching is **not** live but a recording. But yes, cannot help it if you are not convinced with WordWeb

Comment: "Ah, you think this is a live broadcast? Actually, this was recorded yesterday". "You think these are only the highlights? Actually, it is an integral recording." Why would actually mean something different in those two examples?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for showing the meaning.

Well, it certainly relates then.

> The aircraft's **actual** position is so and so altitude. 
>   The cruise's **actual** position is so and so nautical miles southwest to [any] country

This talks about the aircraft's **current, present or actual** position, doesn't it?

Now about the derivative *actually*

WordWeb also describes *actually* to be used as something in the present time.

> [actually (adv. #3)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/ACTUALLY) - *At the present moment.*

And, *actuality*

> [actuality (n. #1.1)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/actuality?q=actuality) - ***Existing*** conditions or facts.

Here, it's not **directly** related to the present, current but *existing* is also *time* related, isn't it?

Am I still missing something?

Comment: Actually (really! :), it's more of an "accidental semantic overlap" that *actual=real* could be said to mean the same as *actual = here, now*. OED's definition A 5: *orig. Sc. In operation or existence at the time; present, current. **Now rare.*** As they point out, it's often difficult to distinguish this sense from their definition A 2a. *Existing in fact, real; carried out, acted in reality. Opposed to potential, possible, ideal, etc.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you, I’ve got it, very valuable indeed, I understand how a native thinks when using this word.